# Django generic view Delete but not immediately

Tags: django, audit

User sometimes do things they should not do and if you ask them they say I don't know...

Is there a way to alter the default behavior of deleteview?

Someway to create a bin table where all deleted records go, with a field of who and when the deletion has been made?

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView

class EntryDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = MYMODEL
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mymodel_app:mymodel')
```

Should I replace it with a request and create another model same as the one that should be deleted and use this model for logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [django-reversion](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#restoring-deleted-model-instances).  You can store history changes to your model and even restore deleted objects.